# SpriteKit: White Background As SKScene

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, storyboard, skscene

I have a Swift project including the `SpriteKit` framework. When I run the program without anything on it, the screen is black and the node counter at 1. The `Main.storyboard` is entirely white and the class in it is set to `SKView`. Is the node counter wrong? Shouldn't it be 0 and why is the background black instead of white?

Maybe some necessary code where the mistake is:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene() // class GameScene is a subclass of SKScene

    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    scene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node counter is right. First of all you set the node couter for `skView` object with this line of code:

```
skView.showsNodeCount = true
```

Then you add object to this `skView` with this line:

```
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

This action set node counter to `1`. Your scene is this single node on `skView`

About black screen: this is default background color for scene, you can change it with this code for example:

```
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

And your scene will be red